# Complex Analysis - Odd Function Rule

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the following question as seen below. In order to solve it I'm thinking of removing the $i$ from the Arg of sine, since sine is an odd function. Can I do this? Please let me know if this is a legal operation:

**Question:** Solve
$$
\sinh(iz) = -i
$$
**Solution:**
$$
\sin(iz) = i 
$$
$$
i\sin(z) = i
$$
$$
\sin(z) = 1
$$

and continue this way?

Comment: You can not do that !! An odd function is when $f(-z)=-f(z)$, which does not allow you to remove the $i$. **Hint:** Prove that $\sin(iz)=i\sinh(z)$.

Comment: lol okay thanks I'll work on something tonight and try to post it soon after.

Comment: @AlonsoDelfín I still end up stuck with an extra term, the sin z. The only way to get ride of it is let z=k(pi); k=0,1,2,...

This is what I did:

sinh (iz) = [e^(iz)-e^(iz)]/2 * -i/-i = -i[(e^(-iz)-e^(iz))/2i] = -i sin(z)



I'm sorry, I just realized that I posted the wrong question in my previous post. The questions is actually the following: Solve:

sinh (iz) = -i
We know that sinh(z) = [e^z - e^(-z)]/2, so that

sin h

Comment: Then please edit your question to put the good one. And here it is a new **Hint:** Recall that $e^z$ is periodic, with period $2\pi i$, then what happens with $\sinh(iz)$ if $z= -\pi/2$? And now if $z=-\pi/2 + 2 \pi$ ? Can you follow from here?

Comment: @AlonsoDelfín 
So this is what I have, it's simple though:

since sin(z) = -i sinh (iz) I substituted it in to get;

-sin (z) / i = i;

-sin (z) = -1;

sin (z) = 1;

true for; 

z=Pi/2 + 2Pik; k=0,1,2...


How does this look? Is it complete enough?

Comment: Looks like you are missing a $-$ sign. In your line of though you must end by solving $\sin(z)=-1.$ Thus, the solutions to the equation $\sinh(iz)=-i$, are in fact $z=-\pi/2 + 2\pi k$ with $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I get it now, thank you.